# Reinitialize fix delay in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

As per my requirement, I have to execute some particular code after certain period of time. To do the same I have chose `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` and it's working fine for me. But according to my another requirement, the time mentioned in `fixedDelay` should be configurable at runtime. Means, currently total Delay is 5 seconds but latter if user want then can change the time into 60 seconds and in runtime `fixedDelay` will run after 60 seconds. Any help would be appreciable.

Please see the code:

```
static int i = 0;
    static ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    static Runnable runnable;
    static ScheduledFuture<?> future;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        executor = Executors
                .newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside runnable" + i++);
                changeDelay();
            }
        };
        future =
                executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    public static void changeDelay() {
        future.cancel(false);
        future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Here I have used changeDelay method to change the delay time. But it's not working.

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` where `delay` is a variable supplied by external classes?

Comment: It works. See the example in the answer. Your test is not very good because the initial task runs with a delay of 0 than is right away canceled and the new task has a delay of 0 and so on, you can't see the dalays.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to keep the reference of the returned `ScheduledFuture<?>` object:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> handle =
       scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

With this reference you cancel the current task and create another one with the new delay:

```
handle.cancel(false);    
handle = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here is an example:

```
public class Test5 {
    static int i = 0;
    static ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    static Runnable runnable;
    static ScheduledFuture<?> future;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
        executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside runnable" + i++);
            }
        };
        future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(20000l);

        changeDelay();
    }

    public static void changeDelay() {
        boolean res = future.cancel(false);

        System.out.println("Previous task canceled: " + res);

        future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i change the timing back and forth depending on a condition?
Currently once i changed the scheduled time, I am not able to reschedule it

Answer (score 4):

As I see `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, initDelay , delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` returns `ScheduledFuture` which **doesn't** have a method `setDelay(delay)` which will allow it to **change the delay** once created.

The best option would be to **cancel** the current runnable `ScheduledFuture.cancel(false)` and start a new scheduled task with the help of `scheduleWithFixedDelay` using new delay value.

**DO NOT CALL** `changeDelay` from `run` method. Instead call it from `main` method itself like below

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduledExecutorExample {
    static int i = 0;
    static ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    static Runnable runnable;
    static ScheduledFuture<?> future;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside runnable" + i++);
            }
        };
        future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000); //sleeping for 2 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        changeDelay();
    }

    public static void changeDelay() {
        future.cancel(false);
        future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

You see that after a while the delay changes to 10 seconds from 2 seconds