# ScheduledExecutorService change delay repeatedly

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a task I want to run where the delay will keep changing (i.e. - no fixed interval).

I want a thread and loops infinitely that finds the delay value, inputs this into the executor and then once that task is done find the new delay value etc..

My current 'basic' implementation:

```
long targetTime = findNextTime()/1000;
long currentTime = System.curentTimeMillis()/1000;

delay = targetTime - currentTime;

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

Runnable task = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Test Task");

        ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduler.schedule(this, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

How can I get it to find the new delay and keep repeating this task?

Should I poll for `future` to be done and then do a recursive loop? I try this and I get an error.

Comment: Move the delay calculation into `run()` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some answer to resolve this.[Reinitialize fix delay in ScheduledExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333244/reinitialize-fix-delay-in-scheduledexecutorservice) and
[How to change Spring's @Scheduled fixedDelay at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333244/reinitialize-fix-delay-in-scheduledexecutorservice)

here i support another method to realize this-repeated submit task to `ExecutorService`

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private ExecutorService executor;

    public Task(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "   Hello World");
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(random.nextInt() % 100);
            executor.execute(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```